# issue in rendering page using webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

i am new to asp.net and webmatrix and i am trying to build a solution using tutorial provided on asp.net. everything worked just fine until i made css file ( copied the code from tutorial) and passed layout in my code that is using copied css. 
i wrote:
@{
    Layout = "~_Layout.cshtml";
it's not rendering my page and a mistake pops up: 
" The layout page "~/_Layout.cshtml" could not be found at the following path: "~/_Layout.cshtml". "

does anyone have a clue what am i doing wrong? 
thanks!

Comment: The layout is missing in the root level of the project.

Comment: When i clicked on root of the project (WebPagesMovie) and made a new cshtml file, _Layout.cshtml was created in bin folder. Should it be created somewhere else? i strictly followed the tutorial.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a Layouts folder if not available. Put your _Layout.cshtml file into the Layout folder then

```
Layout = "~/Layouts/_Layout.cshtml";
```

To reuse the the _Layout.cshtml for all pages in your project, open the _PageStart.cshtml file or create one and paste the code there.

If you desire not the use the Layout on a particular file, simply use

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
```

at the top of the page.